# Excluir item de um array e reordená-lo - PHP

Tags: php, array

É o seguinte:

Tenho um array, mais ou menos desse jeito:

```
$array = [
   [0] => 'Fellipe',
   [1] => 'Fábio',
   [2] => 'Mateus',
   [3] => 'Gustavo'
];
```

Eu gostaria que quando eu retirasse um item desse array:

unset($array[2]);

Eu pudesse reordená-lo dessa seguinte forma:

```
$array = [
   [0] => 'Fellipe',
   [1] => 'Fábio',
   [2] => 'Gustavo'
];
```

Tem alguma maneira de fazer isso???

Comment: Acredito que o ksort/uksort faça isso sem problemas.

Comment: @Inkeliz pelo que eu entendi, ele quer reindexar as chaves ( deixar `0` `1` `2`, e não `0` `1` `3`, faltando o `2` que foi removido). Neste caso bastaria o `array_values`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Respondendo a pergunta ...

Sempre que quiser ignorar as chaves de um array, basta usar a função:

[`array_values ( array $input ): array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php)

Demonstrando no seu código:

```
$array = [
   0 => 'Fellipe',
   1 => 'Fábio',
   2 => 'Mateus',
   3 => 'Gustavo'
];

unset($array[2]);

$array = array_values( $array );
```

Resultado:

> ```
> Array
> ```

```
(
    [0] => Fellipe
    [1] => Fábio
    [2] => Gustavo
)
```

Veja o código funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/5rWWgP)**.

### ... e propondo uma alternativa mais simples:

Você pode remover um ítem e manter a ordenação de uma vez só com esta função:

[`array_splice( array &$input, int $offset [, int $length [, mixed $replacement ]] ): array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-splice.php)

Aplicando no seu código, basta isto:

```
$array = [
   0 => 'Fellipe',
   1 => 'Fábio',
   2 => 'Mateus',
   3 => 'Gustavo'
];

array_splice( $array, 2, 1 );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/bPipBE)**.

No caso, o `2` é o ítem inicial a ser removido, e o `1` a quantidade a remover.

Importante:o `array_splice` trabalha direto no *array*. Neste caso não deve ser usado `$array = array_splice( $array, 2, 1 );`, senão o efeito vai ser o inverso. O retorno é o que foi removido, e não o que sobrou.

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo que eu estava procurando. Obrigado mesmo.